# AngularJs ng-if is not working for nested ng-if

Tags: angularjs

In the code below the 2nd checkbox does not work when the 1st checkbox is clicked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JF0IftvWx7Ew3N43Csji?p=preview

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="animations.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         Click me: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" /><br/>
         Show when checked:
         <span  ng-if="checked==true" class="animate-if">
             <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked1" ng-init="checked1=true" />
         </span>
         <br>
         <span  ng-if="checked1==true" class="animate-if">
          test <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked2" ng-init="checked2=true" />
         </span>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to mark an accepted answer or give a reason why none of these are acceptable as proper SO etiquette.

Answer (score 18):

As noted `ng-if` creates it's own scope.

You're setting `checked1` inside what I'm calling "Inner Scope 1". Then using it in "Outer Scope".  "Outer Scope" can't see into "Inner Scope 1" so  javascript creates a new variable `checked1` on "Outer Scope".  Now **you have two entirely different variables both called`checked1`**- one on "Outer Scope" and one on "Inner Scope1".  This is not what you want.

[image]

**To fix this you need to set `checked1` on the same scope as you'll use it**- "Outer Scope".  "Outer Scope" is the parent of "Inner Scope1" so **we can use `$parent.checked1`** like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checked1" ng-init="checked1=true" />
```

Now there's only one copy of `checked1`- the one on "Outer Scope".  And it works, check it out on this updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XaPWYvYLrFRZdN2OYn6x?p=preview

Comment: Upvoted for the nice graphic explanation. This should be marked as valid.

Answer (score 6):

`ngIf` creates a different scope. Use `$parent`:

```
<span ng-if="checked==true" class="animate-if">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checked1" 
    ng-init="$parent.checked1=true" />
</span>
<br>
<span ng-if="checked1==true" class="animate-if">
    test <input type="checkbox" ng-model="$parent.checked2" 
    ng-init="$parent.checked2=true" />
</span>
```

<kbd>**[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJ6rHNTXZy3fU3GmGGDD?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angIf) instead of ngIf. ngShow helps because it doesn't create child scope. See result [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jaSNFyi2QHE5v1WJeDw6?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that you are using primitive type (boolean) for your data model. Generally it is admit that you should not use primitive types for two way data binding. If you want to know why I encourage you to read this [article](http://crlog.info/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/) important part being :

> This means that, if a property changes within a local scope, the original/parent version of the property isn’t updated with those changes.

In your case what is happening is :
- You are using primitive type boolean
- ngIf creates/destroy its scope while inheriting from its parent scope
- Every change made within the ngIf local scope is never propagated to the parent.
- Hence no update on the nested if.

To fix the issue please use a JS object to hold your check boxes values as follows :

```
<body>
  Click me:
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.first" ng-init="checkboxes = {first : true, second:true, third:true}" />
  <br/>Show when checked:
  <span ng-if="checkboxes.first==true" class="animate-if">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.second" />
 </span>
  <br>
  <span ng-if="checkboxes.second==true" class="animate-if">
  test <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.third"/>
 </span>

</body>
```

Note that the check boxes are now bound to boolean values inside a js object.

[Modifyied working Plunker over here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0rI8hW86wgKZnsecYxve?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue has to do with the fact that you are **not** nesting the `ng-if`.  The two `span` tags are siblings.

So, my theory is that when the compile phase occurs, the `ng-if` that the `Third` depends on cannot be executed.  So, it cannot build up the entire `Third` part of the template.

[This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V3tXzX?p=preview) is working (with nested elements).

```
<div>First <input type="checkbox" ng-model="first" ng-init="first = true"/></div>
<div ng-if="first">
  Second  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="second" ng-init="second = true"/>
  <div ng-if="second">
    Third  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="third" ng-init="third = true"/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

If I change my [plunker to this](http://plnkr.co/edit/6UrxtT?p=preview), it is not working (with siblings):

```
<div>First <input type="checkbox" ng-model="first" ng-init="first = true"/></div>
<div ng-if="first">
  Second  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="second" ng-init="second = true"/>
</div>
<div ng-if="second">
  Third  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="third" ng-init="third = true"/> 
</div>
```